# Printing random names on a file

Tags: python, list, file, random

I was wondering how to print random names from a file. Basically there are 3 files which are surnames,male names and female names. The files have more than just the names. They have numbers as well. Here's an example of what the file looks like:

```
    SMITH   1.006    2,501,922  1
    JOHNSON 0.81     2,014,470  2
    WILLIAMS    0.699    1,738,413  3
    JONES   0.621    1,544,427  4
    BROWN   0.621    1,544,427  5
    DAVIS   0.48     1,193,760  6
    MILLER  0.424    1,054,488  7
    WILSON  0.339    843,093    8
    MOORE   0.312    775,944    9
```

I want the output to print out a last name and first name(no numbers) Here is my code so far. It works but it prints out the numbers.

import random

```
def random_names(surname,male_names,female_names,integer):
names1 = open('surnames.txt', 'r')
names2 = open('malenames.txt', 'r')
names3 = open('femalenames.txt', 'r')
read1=names1.read().split()
read2=names2.read().split()
read3=names3.read().split()

gender_options = ('male', 'female')
count = 0

while count<integer:
    gender_pick=random.choice(gender_options)

    if gender_pick == 'male':
        first_name=random.choice(read2)
    elif gender_pick == 'female':
        first_name=random.choice(read3)

    last_name=random.choice(read1)
    print (first_name,last_name)
    count = count+1


random_names('surnames.txt', 'malenames.txt', 'femalenames.txt',10)
```

Even when I modify it to read2[0] read1[0] read3[0], it just prints out the letters.

```
J M
S H
E T
R I
A I
M H
J S
A I
M I
Y S
```

Comment: What is your modification for `read2[0]`  , `read1[0]` , etc?

Comment: Also, in your `txt` files are all the columns separated by a specific amount of whitespaces ( or is it arbitrary amount of whitespaces) ?

Comment: `names1.read().split()` will read the _entire file_, and then split on _all_ whitespace including linefeeds, spaces, and tabs. You'd end up with something like `['SMITH', '1.006', '2,501,922', '1', JOHNSON 0.81 ]`.

Comment: @AnandSKumar I changed the part in the while loop.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Mostly separated by tabs. The part after the decimal part is separated by a tab and a space.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Anyway to fix it?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to fix it - you'll have to develop and use an algorithm that goes over each line in the file and processes it individually, building up a suitable data structure. `for line in names1:` is a popular start to this task.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function `get_names(filename)` that extracts all names from a file e.g.:

```
def get_names(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        return [line.split(None, 1)[0] for line in file if line.strip()]
```

Test it *separately* and then use it in your script e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import itertools
import random

def generate_random_names(surnames, male_names, female_names,
                          choose=random.choice):
    while True:
        # make male/female names equally likely
        forename = choose(choose([male_names, female_names]))
        yield forename, choose(surnames)

name_lists = map(get_names, ['surnames.txt', 'malenames.txt', 'femalenames.txt'])
fullnames = generate_random_names(*name_lists)    
print(list(itertools.islice(fullnames, 50)))
```

This code may generate duplicate full names. To choose `k` *unique* random elements from a population use `random.sample()` instead.